# How to iterate over rows of a single column based on value of another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is the dataset I am working on right now.
[image: Dataset]

I want to find the maximum value of the cycle column for a single value of the id column. For ex, I want to find out the max cycle value for id-1, id-2 and so on but I can't really figure out the loop logic. How do I get the code to ouptut maximum cycle value for particular id? My dataset has id values from 1-100 so the code should give me a 100 max cycle values.

Comment: can you give some example data? Also, use pandas split-apply-combine: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: df.groupby('id').max()

Comment: replace image by actual data please

Comment: @Wen .groupby() worked. Thanks alot!

Comment: @NicoAlbers sorry for not being able to provide the data. I worked around with the solution provided by Wen and got the answer. Thank you for the SAC reference though

Answer (score -1):

it's not a loop. you can use a pivot table to find your answer:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html